# System V Messaging Queues

Tags: multithreading, message-queue

I am writing an app that there is one mesage queue and two process listening to that. How can I prevent one reading it before other ?

The scenario is : 
there is a server app which reads the queue and sends the message to other queues. ( onc server and multiple clients with different message queues )

but the message between a client and server is going and coming from the same queue thus; I can't guarantee that server takes the message before client thread ( which reads incomings ) does.

Can you help me to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution. My mistake to not to read manuals correctly.

```
ssize_t msgrcv(int msqid, struct msgbuf *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp, int msgflg);
```

parameter 4 is used for this. If I set the message flag for client it will be enoughto handle!